# Ext JS Load data into a form automatically

Tags: extjs

I'm wondering how to load data into a form. I have already a store for the appropriate grid but the model is different. I'm using the MVC approach. So basicly I need to load the data into the form when the form is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use form.loadRecord(record) to load a model into a form.

If a form field has a name that matches the name of a field on the model, then that value will get loaded into the form field.

What does

> I have already a store for the appropriate grid but the model is
>   different

mean?

Comment: I just wanted to say that I can'reuse the model and store of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

With limited details, I could just give you hints.

Make sure you load your **View** from your **Controller**.
Your view should be connected to a **Store** .The Store must be connected to the **Model**.

**Model** is composed of *`Data and Fields`* or it is otherwise called the *`actual schema`*. You can also define the *`proxy`* in the **Model** or **Store**.

Follow this approach and you will be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: And at what point are the data loaded into the form ? I don't want to have the store autoload:true.

Comment: @user49126, No problem. set autoLoad:false and then load your store from your controller when you need to .. like this `var store = this.getMyStore();
store.load();`

Comment: And how can I bind the store to the form ?

Comment: @user49126, Without looking the code i can't give you accurate results. However, try this way.. `Ext.getCmp('yourformid').bindStore('yourstoreid');`

Comment: There isn't a bindStore method on a form.